# Change Organization Owner in Microsoft DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I want to permanently change ownership of an organization in my Microsoft DevOps account

When I changed the owner, I still have the right to change it again. Any advice, how can I transfer the rights to the organization irrevocably?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure the prerequisites have been completed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-ownership?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at it on my end and it's possible you still have the rights to change the owner because you're a member of the Project Collection Administration. The ADO documentation also mentions that as a prerequisite to be able to change the Organization Owner.

> ## Change the organization owner
>
> ### Prerequisites
>
> You must be a Project Collection Administrator or an Organization Owner.

You should remove yourself from the Project Collection Administrator and will then not be able to change the Organization Owner.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-ownership?view=azure-devops